# Setting learning rate for Stochastic Weight Averaging in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch

Following is a small working code for Stochastic Weight Averaging in Pytorch taken from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.1/optim.html#putting-it-all-together).

```
loader, optimizer, model, loss_fn = ...
swa_model = torch.optim.swa_utils.AveragedModel(model)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=300)
swa_start = 160
swa_scheduler = SWALR(optimizer, swa_lr=0.05)

for epoch in range(300):
    for input, target in loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_fn(model(input), target).backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if epoch > swa_start:
            swa_model.update_parameters(model)
            swa_scheduler.step()
        else:
            scheduler.step()

    # Update bn statistics for the swa_model at the end
    torch.optim.swa_utils.update_bn(loader, swa_model)
    # Use swa_model to make predictions on test data
    preds = swa_model(test_input)
```

In this code after 160th epoch the `swa_scheduler` is used instead of the usual `scheduler`. What does `swa_lr` signify? The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.1/optim.html#swa-learning-rate-schedules) says,

> Typically, in SWA the learning rate is set to a high constant value. SWALR is a learning rate scheduler that anneals the learning rate to a fixed value, and then keeps it constant.

1. So what happens to the learning rate of the `optimizer` after 160th epoch?
2. Does `swa_lr` affect the `optimizer` learning rate?

Suppose that at the beginning of the code the `optimizer` was `ADAM` initialized with a learning rate of `1e-4`. Then does the above code imply that for the first 160 epochs the learning rate for training will be `1e-4` and then for the remaining number of epochs it will be `swa_lr=0.05`? If yes, is it a good idea to define `swa_lr` also to `1e-4`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- > does the above code imply that for the first *160* epochs the learning rate for training will be `1e-4`

  No it won't be equal to `1e-4`, during the first 160 epochs the learning rate is managed by the first scheduler `scheduler`. This one is a initialize as a [`torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR.html). The learning rate will follow this curve:

  [image]

---

- > for the remaining number of epochs it will be `swa_lr=0.05`

  This is partially true, during the second part - from epoch *160* - the optimizer's learning rate will be handled by the second scheduler `swa_scheduler`. This one is initialized as a [`torch.optim.swa_utils.SWALR`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#swa-learning-rate-schedules). You can read on the documentation page:

  > SWALR is a learning rate scheduler that **anneals the learning rate to a fixed value [`swa_lr`], and then keeps it constant**.

  By default (cf. [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/swa_utils.py#L212)), the number of epochs before annealing is equal to *10*. Therefore the learning rate from epoch *170* to epoch *300* will be equal to `swa_lr` and will stay this way. The second part will be:

  [image]

  This complete profile, *i.e.* both parts:

  [image]

---

- > If yes, is it a good idea to define `swa_lr` also to `1e-4`

  It is mentioned in the docs:

  > Typically, in SWA the learning rate is set to a high constant value.

  Setting `swa_lr` to `1e-4` would result in the following learning-rate profile:

  [image]

Comment: Thanks. One more question. To save the SWA model will this work: `torch.save({'model': swa_model.state_dict()},os.path.join('weights_{}'.format(epoch)))`?